# how to make function with dividing? i have a trouble with e nums function. Problem with dividing by zero, because i have 1/n in it

Tags: manim

```
self.axes = Axes(
    x_range=(-10, 10, 3),
    y_range=(-10, 10, 3)
)
self.f = lambda x: (1+1/x)**x
curve = self.axes.plot(self.f, color= RED)
self.play(Create(self.axes), Create(curve))
self.interactive_embed()
```

gives me this:

> array must not contain infs or NaNs
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
> self.f = lambda x: (1+1/x)**x

I tried to make spacing by 3< so it will skip 0, but it didn't help. When I'm trying this:

```
self.axes = Axes((1, 10), (2, 3))
```

it works, but I need axes starting from -10 to 10 on both

Answer (score 0):

While I was plotting the same function, the function was still graphed even though there were warnings. If you want them gone, though, just write a function instead:

```
def func(x):
    if x != 0:
        return (1+(1/x))**x
    else:
        return 0
```

and then use it like this:

```
graph = axes.plot(lambda x: func(x))
```